# Add AM/PM to datepicker?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uidatepicker

My UIDatePicker is set to UIDatePickerModeTime but on the apple documentation it says `The date picker displays hours, minutes, and (optionally) an AM/PM designation. The exact items shown and their order depend upon the locale set. An example of this mode is [ 6 | 53 | PM ].`. How do i add AM/PM because on my device, those aren't options and it instead uses a 24 hour clock?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This will depend on the settings of the user. If you go to Settings -> General -> Date & Time. there is a "24-Hour" time switch, and based on that users will have the AM/PM indicator on your picker.

Comment: This is true, but it can easily be overruled by setting the locale if needed for some reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately `UIDatePicker` doesn't have an option for that; it always respects the device option of 12-hour or 24-hour time.

If you *must* have an AM/PM component you may have to go with a custom `UIPickerView` instead, and build an `NSDate` out of its components manually.

Comment: try datepicker.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];

Answer (score 1):

This thread is somewhat old, but maybe this will be useful to someone else...

As written in the original question, the picker will respect the locale. So, if you what to overrule the system-settings you can set the desired locale on the picker like this:

```
picker.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "en")
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things to check,

- [UIDatePicker](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker/mode) has `mode` which needs to be either set to `.time` or `.dateAndTime` in order to support AM/PM format.
- set locale to a locale that supports AM/PM, eg "en_US_POSIX", if your locale is set to `current`, it will read system locale.