# UIDatePicker 24h

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add AM/PM to datepicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822722/add-am-pm-to-datepicker)

I have UIDatePicker. If I select region Russia I have 24h, if I select USA I have 12h AM/PM.
How doing that I can select any region and have 24h?

```
datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 45, 325, 250)];
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
datePicker.hidden = YES;
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(changeDateInLabel:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

- (void)changeDateInLabel:(id)sender{
     NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]autorelease]; 
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle]; 
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle]; 
    datelabel.text=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[datePicker date]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because the locale (russia) defaults to 24 hours. Its a limitation / issue with the SDK.

Easiest fix:

```
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[datePicker setLocale:locale];
[locale release];
```

Comment: i doing as you write and I havn't got 24h in UIDatePicker.
and I doing NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ru_RU"];
[datePicker setLocale:locale];
[locale release];
and it not work

Comment: @Pavel The locale identifier for Russia is just "ru".